# Merging dataframes of different length by matching dates

Tags: r, merge, time-series, rbind

I have two dataframes of different lengths (n=3012 and 3008) that I need to merge based upon date.  I have tried using the merge and rbindfill functions but had no success.  The common thread between the two dataframes is date_time however both df2 does not have all of the same values as df1.

df1

```
ID date_time Q_cfs Data_Code
68 2016-11-01 00:00:00   353         P
69 2016-11-01 00:15:00   356         P
70 2016-11-01 00:30:00   357         P
71 2016-11-01 00:45:00   356         P
72 2016-11-01 01:00:00   358         P
73 2016-11-01 01:15:00   355         P
```

df2

```
ID  stage           date_time
1  4.82 2016-11-01 00:00:00
2  4.83 2016-11-01 00:15:00
3  4.84 2016-11-01 00:30:00
4  4.85 2016-11-01 00:45:00
5  4.86 2016-11-01 01:00:00
6  4.87 2016-11-01 01:15:00
```

I tried using merge (below) but it did not work since the column lengths are different.

```
DF_New<- merge(df1,df2, by.x = df1$date_time, by.y = df2$date_time)
```

I also tried using rbind.fill (below) but it replaced all the values of df2 with .

```
DF_New <- rbind.fill(df1,df2)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your assumptions about the reason for failure are incorrect. Merges with dataframes of unequal row number are typical. If you need to coerce to Date-class then use `as.Date`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `dplyr` package and try `left_join()`. This returns all rows from `df1` and all columns from both `df1` and `df2`. Any rows in `df1` with no match will receive `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = "date_time")
```

Check out the other types of join you can have with `?join`.

Answer (score 0):

You have it almost correct. All you need to do, is to add one more argument into your function, like in the example below:

```
DF_New<- merge(df1,df2, by.x = df1$date_time, by.y = df2$date_time, all=TRUE)
```

Comment: I still get the following error.

    Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match number of columns

Comment: Then try just: by"date_time

Comment: DF_New<- merge(df1,df2, by.x = df1$date_time, by.y = df2$date_time, all=TRUE)

Comment: Then try just:
DF_New<- merge(df1,df2, by="date_value", all=TRUE)

Comment: The dataframes are now merging but they are not matching based upon date_time stamp. Both dataframes are set for the same timezone but there is a 7 hour offset in the time. Any suggestions?